# Laravel : Overwrite Socialite Provider to add new fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I want to extend/overwrite my LinkedInProvider.php (in vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two) to add new fields in the Linkedin Request.

I've create a new LinkedInProvider.php (in app\Providers) with the following code :

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\AbstractProvider;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\ProviderInterface;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\User;

class LinkedInProvider extends AbstractProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
/**
 * The scopes being requested.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $scopes = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress'];

/**
 * The separating character for the requested scopes.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $scopeSeparator = ' ';

/**
 * The fields that are included in the profile.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fields = [
    'id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'formatted-name',
    'email-address', 'headline', 'location', 'industry', 'positions',
    'public-profile-url', 'picture-url', 'picture-urls::(original)',
];

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getAuthUrl($state)
{
    return $this->buildAuthUrlFromBase('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization', $state);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getTokenUrl()
{
    return 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken';
}

/**
 * Get the POST fields for the token request.
 *
 * @param  string  $code
 * @return array
 */
protected function getTokenFields($code)
{
    return parent::getTokenFields($code) + ['grant_type' => 'authorization_code'];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getUserByToken($token)
{
    $fields = implode(',', $this->fields);

    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:('.$fields.')';

    $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get($url, [
        'headers' => [
            'x-li-format' => 'json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
        ],
    ]);

    return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
{
    return (new User)->setRaw($user)->map([
        'id' => $user['id'], 'nickname' => null, 'name' => Arr::get($user, 'formattedName'),
        'email' => Arr::get($user, 'emailAddress'), 'avatar' => Arr::get($user, 'pictureUrl'),
        'avatar_original' => Arr::get($user, 'pictureUrls.values.0'),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Set the user fields to request from LinkedIn.
 *
 * @param  array  $fields
 * @return $this
 */
public function fields(array $fields)
{
    $this->fields = $fields;

    return $this;
}
```

}

But now, I've got this error :

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Laravel\Socialite\Two\AbstractProvider::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called in G:\laragon\www\localhost\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php on line 201
```

I know I can install Socialite Manager, but I just want to overwrite the fields list to add new field (like position and industry)

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't have to overwrite/extend the whole class. In the `Laravel\Socialite\Two\User` object that is being created, there is a `$user` property, which contains the raw information the provider sent back.

When making the request, you can set the fields you want LinkedIn to return in your controller method:

```php
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    $fields = [
        'id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'formatted-name',
        'email-address', 'headline', 'location', 'industry',
        'public-profile-url', 'picture-url', 'picture-urls:(original)',
        'positions', 'summary' // <-- additional fields here
    ];

    return Socialite::driver('linkedin')->fields($fields)->redirect();
}
```

You can see two additional fields being requested, positions and summary, which aren't included by default.

Happy hacking!